# azure container with RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-rbac

I am trying to understand how can I run a python application inside azure container that can spin up various resources like VM, route-table inside resource group of Azure.

http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Looks like the examples provided in azure python sdk sets authentication stuff like credentials, subscription ID, etc.

Is there a way to avoid setting up of this information by using Role Based Access Control ? What if I provide container an Contributor access to the resource group, in that case, would i able to avoid setting up authentication variables and still achieve creating resources or atleast read/access resources in resource group ?

Answer (score 0):

No, how do you think that would work? In order to be able to create\read\modify resources you need permissions (else anyone would be able to do that). There is no way to do that without some sort of Auth.

Comment: So in AWS - at least in lambda, I can preconfigure lambda at deployment time and provide necessary roles/permissions and in the code, I can just do import boto3 and access resources and it works flowlessly. So I am exploring if Azure has similar mechanisms in place.

Comment: ah, ic what you mean, there might be something like this for functions, but not for containers

Comment: do you know any example of like that even for a azure functions? it would be helpful too